# Sqoop authenticates but fails to start a map reduce job

Tags: sql-server-2008, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to transfer data using sqoop from HDFS to the MSSQL server. But for some reasons, sqoop hangs at

```
tool.BaseSqoopTool: Enabled debug logging.
sqoop.ConnFactory: Added factory com.microsoft.sqoop.SqlServer.MSSQLServerManagerFactory specified by /usr/lib/sqoop/conf/managers.d/mssqoop-sqlserver
DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.microsoft.sqoop.SqlServer.MSSQLServerManagerFactory
DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: com.microsoft.sqoop.SqlServer.MSSQLServerManagerFactory
INFO SqlServer.MSSQLServerManagerFactory: Using Microsoft's SQL Server - Hadoop Connector
INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Instantiated ConnManager com.microsoft.sqoop.SqlServer.MSSQLServerManager@45db05b2
INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
DEBUG manager.SqlManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.
```

I check the firewall and it is allowing connections without any restrictions. Sqoop gets authenticated but doesnt initiate a map reduce job after it gets authenticated. Any one has faced similar problems before?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `--verbose` to print more information.

Comment: the given stacktrace has been generated with `--verbose` flag already

Answer (score 0):

Is your SQL Server running on a Virtual Machine?  I had a similar problem with Oracle.  I was running Oracle on a VM with a static IP and a Bridged network adapter.  Servers within the same network as the Oracle server could connect fine, but servers outside the network showed these same symptoms.  The solution was to change from a Bridged Interface to a NAT'd interface.  Then you need to set up a port forwarding rule on the host machine to your database server, and make your Sqoop connection to the host machine IP rather than the VM's IP.  It took me several days to get this figured out.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

We has MsSQL server running on our machines. The problem was that the particular version of JVM (Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)) had bug and caused the client to hang in the getconnection method.
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7103725
We upgraded to a newer version and things worked fine.